# Service class and attribute value in multithread environnement

Tags: spring-boot

In a spring boot application when we have a class

```
@Service
public class UserService{

   private final String userName;
   private String companyName;
   private List<Operation> operations;

   public void save(User user){
       ...
   }

}
```

Is this class it's stateless?

if there are many request in same thing every request have it's own value for every attribute or every thing is shared?

Comment: Without knowing what happens it is more or less unanswerable. However I doubt it it is stateless giving the names of the variables. The service is a singleton, so everything is shared.